# World resource system for Adventure Game/RPG

Tags: c#, unity3d

I'm beginning the long process of developing an Adventure Game/RPG and I was hoping to get some review on a resource system I'm coming up with.  How it works is, a resource is generic to every resource in the world.  Each resource will have a name, a random yield, and a random quality. So I've created an interface for the generic properties and function each resource will have.

**Interface**

```
public interface IResource{
    string Name {get;set;}
    string Quality {get;set;}
    int Yield{get;set;}
    string ConvertQualityToString();
    int GetResourceYield();
}
```

Then I implement the interface in an actual resource base class.

**Implementation**

```
public class Resource : MonoBehaviour, IResource{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Quality { get; set; }
    public int Yield { get; set; }

    public string ConvertQualityToString(){
        var val = Random.Range(0, 3);
        string quality;
        switch (val){
            case 1:
                quality = "Good";
                break;
            case 2:
                quality = "Great";
                break;
            default:
                quality = "Poor";
                break;
        }
        return quality;
    }

    public int GetResourceYield(){
        var val = Random.Range(1, 25);
        return val;
    }
}
```

And finally, I create the specific resource itself and attach it to my game object in the inspector.

**Resource Class**

```
public class Granite : Resource{
    void Start(){
        Name = "Granite";
        Quality = ConvertQualityToString();
        Yield = GetResourceYield();
    }
}
```

Is this the proper way to work this system?  Obviously, the system actually does work as when I log the values on startup, `Yield` and `Quality` are randomized and the `Name` for each resource object I create is correct.  Is there a better way to do this?  Are there things I should change?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A few notes:

- All `IResource` properties have public setters. Are you absolutely certain that other code should be able to modify those? I'd recommend making these read-only unless you have specific reasons not to.
- `ConvertQualityToString` and `GetResourceYield` look like internal helper methods. Making them part of the `IResource` interface creates a very confusing API: what's the difference between `resource.Yield` and `resource.GetResourceYield()`? With the way the code is structured, I'd expect these methods to be `protected`.
- Are you sure that `string` is a good type for `Quality`? If you've got a fixed number of qualities an `enum` is a more strongly-typed and descriptive choice. And if different qualities have different characteristics then perhaps a `Quality` class makes more sense. Try to avoid writing 'stringly-typed' code.
- `ConvertQualityToString` gives a 33% chance for each quality. Likewise, `GetResourceYield` always produces yields between 1 and 25. Are you sure that's applicable to all resources and in all circumstances? Should quality and yield even be determined by a `Resource` instance itself? What if, for example, some enemies should have a higher chance of dropping high-quality resources? Or what if you want to provide player upgrades that increase the average resource yield?
- What's the point of that `Granite` class? There's no custom logic in there, and the resource name itself is sufficient to distinguish between different resources.
- In `ConvertQualityToString`, there's no need for that local `quality` variable: you can let each `case` return a value directly (which also allows you to remove those `break` statements).
- `ConvertQualityToString` is a strange name: it doesn't really convert anything. Inaccurate and confusing names tend to make code more difficult to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the notes.  There is going to be more to the system, for example, resources will be havestable, which is why I gave the properties public setters.  The `Granite` class will have some logic in it, for example when a player is mining the granite resource, that's what will change the Yield of that specific resource.  As far as the `ConvertQualityToString` and `GetResourceYield` methods go, should I just break them out into a helper class?  Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Harvesting only requires `Yield` to be public (or perhaps better, a public `Harvest` method). And unless the mining mechanism for granite is really different from other resources, you don't need a separate class for it. As for those methods, I'd probably leave them where they are, but I'd make them static. Also, it looks like `IResourceDeposit` would be a more accurate name for how you're using it.